# using spring security plugin in Grails 3

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spring-security

I'm trying to use`Spring security grails plugin` i'm using `Grails 3.3.2` , i used `@Secured` annotation , but i get the below error :

```
 unable to resolve class Secured ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 35, column 5.
   @Secured([
   ^
```

here is by `build.gradle`:

```
 dependencies{
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0'
   }
```

and i applied this to my controller but nothing fixed :

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;
```

also ,from where i can import `SpringSecurityUtils`?

my IDE is `intellij` anything i'm missing ?

Comment: It is impossible to say for sure with such little information but you probably have the IDE out of sync with the dependencies you have expressed in `build.gradle`.  If you open the Gradle view and refresh the project, the IDE will pick up the updates you added to `build.gradle`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown i did refreshing to the dependencies but still getting the same error

Comment: There are any number of things that might be wrong in your setup that could explain this.  Without a sample project which demonstrates the problem it would be difficult to troubleshoot.  The code at https://github.com/jeffbrown/sherifsecurity/blob/0966ec6fb45192cb3f157780c000462f8397a115/grails-app/controllers/sherifquestion/SomeController.groovy#L5 compiles fine with the dependency expressed at https://github.com/jeffbrown/sherifsecurity/blob/0966ec6fb45192cb3f157780c000462f8397a115/build.gradle#L66.

Comment: One thing to look for is make sure your `org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0` dependency is expressed in the application `dependencies { ... }` block and not the `buildscript` one.

Comment: Run your compile with `./gradlew cG` (or on Windows just use `gradlew cG`) and see if you get the error there.

Comment: Hi , the problem was solved but i don't know how , i just closed the IDE then opened it again , then all worked fine !!!!